# Clicking a button automatically in a web browser with python

Tags: python, bots

Sort of like a bot, i have already checked out some sites such as pyjamas and scrapy, I know how to print data of websites, but still dont know how to interact with buttons. Can somebody help me with some demonstarative code?

Lets say i have a form

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

how do i identify the button to be clicked, so that python can click it for me?
If anybody knows any sites with demonstarative code, i would be very pleased.

Comment: huh? what has this to do with Python? If you want to submit data to some webserver then you have to perform a proper HTTP GET/POST request - this is something completely different then reading HTML and parsing it. Perhaps you should understand first what happens on the client and what on the server - basic HTTP know-how should be expectable if you deal with HTML. Tools like mechanize are way to deal with that.

Comment: a HTTP GET/POST request was probably a bad example, if anybody knows KoL mafia, something like this is what i am trying to make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you’re looking to really simulate a browser, you might want to look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), which allows you to control a real web browser.

If the website you’re looking to interface with uses a lot of JavaScript (e.g. `onclick` handlers), it can be very handy.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) for that. It provides an easy way for interacting with websites.