# How to click a button to vote with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm practicing with web scraping in python. I'd like to press a button on a site that votes an item.
Here is the code

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body role="document">
<div id="static page" class="container-fluid">
<div id="page" class="row"></div>
<div id="faucets-list">
<tbody>
<tr class=""></tr>
<tr class=""></tr>
<tr class=""></tr>
<tr class=""></tr>
# an infinite number of nodes, until there's mine
<tr class="">
<td class="vote-col">
<div class="vote-box">
<div class="vote-links">
<a class="vote-link up" data-original-title="I like this faucet" href="#" data-faucet"39274" data-vote"up" data-toggle"tooltip" data-placement="top" title=""></a>
```

And this it the final part but when I manually click on the button:

```
<a data-original-title="I&nbsp;like&nbsp;this&nbsp;faucet" href="#" class="vote-link up voted" data-faucet="39274" data-vote="up" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title=""></a>
```

Can i simulate it with a script in python? I'm still a newbie and I've started learning python recently. P.S: the site is in https. And I cant's use http cause it force to redirect in https.

--UDPATE--
I'm trying with selenium..

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://faucetbox.com/en/list/BTC")
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".vote-link.up")
element_attribute_value = element.get_attribute("data-faucet")
if element_attribute_value == "39274":
    print ("Value: {0}".format(element_attribute_value))
driver.quit()
```

But since there are multiple number for each vote, it always shows the first one... so it never prints that print... How can I do to select my line of html sourcecode end replace it to a line I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clicking a button automatically in a web browser with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693221/clicking-a-button-automatically-in-a-web-browser-with-python)

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check out [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). It is a module for python that allows you to automate tasks like the one you have mentioned above. Try something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://faucetbox.com/en/list/BTC")
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".vote-link.up")
for element in elements:
    element_attribute_value = element.get_attribute("data-faucet")
    if element_attribute_value == "39274":
        print("Value: {0}".format(element_attribute_value))
        element.click()
        break
driver.quit()
```

The difference between what you did and what I did is that I used the `find_elements_by_css_selector` method instead of `find_element_by_css_selector`. The former returns a list of all elements that match the css selector while the latter returns only the first matching element. Then I just iterated through that list with a simple `for` loop and used the same check that you did. I also clicked the element in the loop. Hope this helps!