# How to change element class attribute value using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I lost my credentials.. so I'm creating this new thread. The old question it here if it helps: [How to click a button to vote with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424703/how-to-click-a-button-to-vote-with-python)

I'd like to change this line:

```
<a data-original-title="I&nbsp;like&nbsp;this&nbsp;faucet" href="#" class="vote-link up" data-faucet="39274" data-vote="up" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a>
```

to this:

```
<a data-original-title="I&nbsp;like&nbsp;this&nbsp;faucet" href="#" class="vote-link up voted" data-faucet="39274" data-vote="up" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a>
```

So that the vote is set changing `vote-link up` to `vote-link up voted`.

But the problem is that in that site, there are severals items to vote, and the element "data-faucet" changes. If I use this script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("linkurl")
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".vote-link.up")
element_attribute_value = element.get_attribute("data-faucet")
if element_attribute_value == "39274":
    print ("Value: {0}".format(element_attribute_value))
driver.quit()
```

But it obsiusly doesn't print anything, cause the first attribute value has another number. How can I select my line with the input of the number of `data-faucet` element, so I can replace it with `vote-link up voted`?

I only can do this selenium? Is there another way without using a real browser?

Anyway, this is the structure of the webpage:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body role="document">
<div id="static page" class="container-fluid">
<div id="page" class="row"></div>
<div id="faucets-list">
<tbody>
<tr class=""></tr>
<tr class=""></tr>
<tr class=""></tr>
<tr class=""></tr>
# an infinite number of nodes, until there's mine
<tr class="">
<td class="vote-col">
<div class="vote-box">
<div class="vote-links">
<a class="vote-link up" data-original-title="I like this faucet" href="#" data-faucet"39274" data-vote"up" data-toggle"tooltip" data-placement="top" title=""></a>
```

The site is this: https://faucetbox.com/en/list/BTC

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From comments:-

> Do you want to interact with element which has `data-faucet` attribute value `39274`??
>
> exatly! just what I want to do!

You should try using `css_selector` as below :-

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".vote-link.up[data-faucet = '39274']")
```

> ok.. now it selects something in fact if I print(element) terminal shows: `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d54ae232-6d42-455f-a130-097be89adf1e", element="{96385594-1725-4843-bfed-d5a4e7b9af41}")>.` so now that I've selected it, how can I replace "vote-link up" with "vote-link up voted"?

You can replace `class` attribute value using `execute_script()` as below :-

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','vote-link up voted')", element)
```

Comment: ok.. now it selects something in fact if I print(element) terminal shows: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d54ae232-6d42-455f-a130-097be89adf1e", element="{96385594-1725-4843-bfed-d5a4e7b9af41}")>. so now that I've selected it, how can I replace "vote-link up" with "vote-link up voted"?

Comment: Now try using `execute_script()` to set attribute value of the element, try with updated answer and let me know

Comment: just another thing... is it possible to do it with another library that does not open the firefox browser but that executes all in background? I don't want to know how to, just if is it possible

Comment: Yes, it's possible using headless browser, see this link for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549954/java-selenium-how-can-i-get-the-html-of-a-webpage-without-first-loading-the-pag/38550069#38550069

Comment: To make that more generic: 

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2])", element, 'class', 'vote-link up voted')