# how do i click this element using selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My end goal is to click a "download menu" button and in order to get to the button i need to click some optinons before hand. One of the options i am strugling with is this one:

this is what the html looks like when i do an inspect element on the option:

```
<li class=" "><a href="90" id="15">The Pub</a></li>
```

when i click on the option "The Pub" the list class becomes active and reveals a download menu button to a pdf which is what i want to click, like so:

```
<li class="active"><a href="90" id="15">The Pub</a></li>
```

this is what the selector looks like when i do a copy selector on chrome:

```
#\31 5
```

this is what the xpath looks like when i do a copy xpath on chrome:

```
//*[@id="15"]
```

i have tried the following and everytime webdriver can not find it:

> browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#\31 5")
>
> browser.find_element_by_css_selector(r"#\31 5")
>
> browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"15\"]")

Comment: Please show more HTML code around the option,  at least include the  whole dropdown menu and its parent node

Comment: Is it possible to share URL of this web? I think it is not a simple controller.

Comment: At which stage are you exactly stuck to click `<li class=" "><a href="90" id="15">The Pub</a></li>` or `<li class="active"><a href="90" id="15">The Pub</a></li>` ?

Comment: Have you looked to see if there is an IFRAME surrounding these elements? Have you tried locating the element by link text "The Pub"?

Comment: @Buaban i cant share the endpoint as its an intranet site

Comment: @JeffC i have tried both these options and it doesnt find the element

Comment: @DebanjanB both, so when i click on the option the content is displayed and when that happens the class becomes active, ive tried modifying the class name to set it to active but that also doesn't make the content appear

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.find_element_by_id('15').click()
```

Comment: unfortunately did not work, got this error: `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a href="90" id="15">...</a> is not clickable at point (2058, 823). Other element would receive the click: <div class="restaurants-outter-wrap">...</div>
`   i think i may need to make the list class active?

Comment: can you try:
`browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="15"]/..').click()`

Comment: if you need to manually change it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434821/how-to-change-element-class-attribute-value-using-selenium

Comment: firstly thanks for helping, i tried the xpath duggestion but got errors, also tried it with backspacing the quotes and removing the .. but still got this error `Message: element not visible`. i also tried changing the class to active but the content didnt appear even though the class got set to active

Comment: whats the parent to the <li> tag?

Comment: `<ul style="margin-left: 0px; width: 2524px;"><li class="active"><a href="2" id="2">Café &amp; Deli</a></li><li><a href="5" id="4">cafe2o</a></li><li><a href="6" id="5">Café3</a></li><li><a href="7" id="6">The Market</a></li><li><a href="46" id="7">canteen</a></li><li><a href="9" id="8">The Restaurant</a></li><li><a href="74" id="9">The Loft</a></li><li><a href="12" id="10">Cafe4</a></li><li><a href="76" id="13">Ocean cafe</a></li><li><a href="77" id="14">The Restaurant</a></li><li><a href="90" id="15">The Pub </a></li><li><a href="82" id="16">The Garden</a></li></ul>`

Answer (score 0):

```
By.XPath(".//a[contains(.,'The Pub') and count(a[contains(.,'The Pub')]) = 0]");
```