# remove/change a specific element class attribute value using selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have a problem based on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434821/how-to-change-element-class-attribute-value-using-selenium) that has an answer but does not fit for me. I have an element that is not set up like this `class="vote-link up"` where it would be easy to make the class to change its attribute because that is just one word where mine is not similar to it.

The HTML code looks like this `<textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea>`

And I want to remove `display: none;` which are the two last attribute of the HTML code. Or change it to `display: shown;` performing one of the options I have shown would give the same result that I want I just don't know how to do it.

i.e this is what i desire, to change the HTML to this `<textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;"></textarea>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for clarification, <kbd>display is not an attribute</kbd> it's one of the properties of `style` attribute. Here is the [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp) for more information.

Here are the 2 options to handle your scenario.

**Option 1:** Update the style display property value to <kbd>block</kbd>

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("g-recaptcha-response"));
System.out.println("Before updating the property:" + ele.getAttribute("style"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';",ele);
System.out.println("After updating the property:" + ele.getAttribute("style"));
```

**Option 2:** Remove the style > display property

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
ele = driver.findElement(By.id("g-recaptcha-response"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.removeProperty('display')",ele);
System.out.println("After deleting the property:" + ele.getAttribute("style"));
```

Comment: See the second HTML which OP have provided, he was able to remove the property `display: none;` already

Comment: OP want that output, not that he was able to remove the property. As per my understadnign, OP asking how to do it.

Comment: As @supputuri is saying, I'm asking how to do it