# Python webbrowser: simple way of checking when the launch is finished?

Tags: python

I am launching a url with

```
webbrowser.open('url')
```

The problem is that sometimes it takes 5 seconds for the browser to complete its launch and other times 1 second.

I need to know when the browser if done launching so I can start clicking the website with win32api mouse clicks.

Comment: You should probably use [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) instead.

Comment: You are right. I did use selenium and it worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use selenium. It has functions to find elements by x path, css selector. It can also click as instructed. The main benefit of using it: it waits till the page loads. 
 [Clicking a button automatically in a web browser with python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5693221/8496019)

Comment: Thanks. This worked well as selenium knows when the launch is finished.